# How do I dynamically create a list of controls or labels that have the same properties of a pre-existing one VB.net

Tags: vb.net, controls, label, dynamically-generated

When I try to create a list of labels with the same properties as a pre-existing one using the code below, while I end up with a list 10 items long, they all end up having the same name and there ends up only being one label displayed.
I suspect that I am ending up with a list of 10 "pointers" to the same label. (But I'm using the word "New" every chance i get :) )

```
Dim lblList As New List(Of Label)
  For I = 0 To 9
    lblList.Add(New Label)
    lblList(I) = lblExistingLabelWithDesiredProperties
    lblList(I).Name = "lblName" & I.ToString
    lblList(I).Left = 30 + I * 10
  Next
```

As I say I seem to end up with only one label.
I've searched high and low for the answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You end up with a list of 10 **references** to the same label.
If you want to populate the new labels with some/all properties of the initial label, you need to assign them to the newly created ones like:

```
Dim lblList As New List(Of Label)
For I = 0 To 9
  lblList.Add(New Label)
  ' assign the properties
  lblList(I).Top = lblExistingLabelWithDesiredProperties.Top
  lblList(I).Text = lblExistingLabelWithDesiredProperties.Text
  ' and so on
  lblList(I).Name = "lblName" & I.ToString
  lblList(I).Left = 30 + I * 10
Next
```

If you want to show the labels also, you need to add them to a controlls collection of a container ( e.g a form, a panel, a groupbox ).

Comment: Heslacher, are you sure there is no way to copy the properties from one label to an other in just one shot? @Heslacher

Comment: As neither `Control` nor `Label` implement the `IClonable` interface, yes i am as sure as i can.

Comment: Ok, I guess it not the end of the world, but I have to say that I'm surprised. _Thanks alot_.